# Google Maps Javascript API V3 - Continuous Panning

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling

I'm trying to get Google Maps to continuously pan smoothly over unless the user moves the mouse over the map. Using the 'idle' event handler causes a choppy pan animation. Using other events won't give me results. Recursion of my `initPan()` function is just causing the page to crash. Example of the 'idle' continuous pan method [here](http://marcripley.com/panmap.html).

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: markers.sanjose,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        initPan(map);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function() {
        stopPan(map);
    });
}

function initPan(map) {
   map.panBy(5, 0);
}

function stopPan(){
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a lot of views, no comments, but here's my solution if anyone ever comes across this kind of situation.

In triggering repeating methods by user events, such as `panBy()`, I ran into problems with API V3. While V2 had the 'moveend' event, it was replaced with the 'idle' event. However, 'idle' has a short delay after the pan occurs.  Another option is to use the 'bounds_changed' event, but this event fires multiple times per second, causing the map to never load tiles (hence no panning appearance).

I finally solved this issue by adding a timeout delay to the 'bounds_changed', clearing the timeouts that would stack on the multiple event triggers. This is the code snippet that solved the issue.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  if (moving) {
    if (myTimeout) {
      window.clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    }
    myTimeout = window.setTimeout(initPan(map), 2200);
  }
});
```

I found the solution on the [API forum](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/forum.html?place=topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/KTw1WjOhSiE/discussion), and you can see an example of my working continuous panning [here](http://marcripley.com/panmap.html). And if this isn't making any sense, look at the full code on the example, and good luck.

Comment: 1 thing tho... trying this now and there's an issue with not finding the "moving" variable. Where do i initialize that?